# Awaiting a function that calls an async function recursively

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, es6-promise, fs

I have a function that looks like this:

```
function populateMap(directory: string, map, StringMap) {
    fs.promises.readdir(directory).then(files: string[]) => {
        files.forEach(file: string) => {
            const fullPath = path.join(directory, file);
            fs.stat(fullPath, (err: any, stats: any) => {
                if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                   populateFileMap(fullPath, fileMap);
                } else {
                   fileMap[file] = fullPath;
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

What I want to do is recursively walk through the parent directory and store a map of file names to their paths. I know this is working because if I put a console.log(fileMap) under fileMap[file] = fullPath, after the deepest file in the directory, the list is properly populated.

In the file that calls this function, I want to be able to have the full map as such

```
function populateMapWrapper(dir: string) {
    const fileMap: StringMap = {};

    populateMap(dir, fileMap);

    //fileMap should be correctly populated here
}
```

I've tried making populateMap asynchronous, adding a .then() to where it's called in the wrapper function, but if I console.log(fileMap) in the then() function, the fileMap is empty.

I'm not sure if this is because of how javascript passes variables or if there's a gap in my understanding of promises, but I'm wondering if there's an alternative way to do this.

Comment: Yes, converting the callback style to promises is a good idea, as is making it an `async function` where you can `await` those promises. And [don't use `forEach`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37576685/1048572).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that `fs.stat` doesn't return a promise. You need to also use `fs.promises.stat`. Also, when working with promises be careful about using `forEach`, because it doesn't `await` for each of the `forEach` callbacks. You could instead use `map` with `Promise.all()`

One solution:

```
function populateMap(directory: string, map) {
  return fs.promises.readdir(directory).then((files: string[]) => {
    return Promise.all(
      files.map((file: string) => {
        const fullPath = path.join(directory, file);
        return fs.promises.stat(fullPath).then(stats => {
          if (stats.isDirectory()) {
            return populateMap(fullPath, map);
          } else {
            map[file] = fullPath;
          }
        })
      }))
  })
}
```

Then you would have to use `await` in the wrapper:

```
async function populateMapWrapper(dir: string) {
    const fileMap: StringMap = {};

    await populateMap(dir, fileMap);

    //fileMap should be correctly populated here
}
```

However, a more readable solution would be to make use of `await` whenever possible. Something like:

```
async function populateMap (directory: string, map) {
  const files = await fs.promises.readdir(directory)
  for (const file of files) {
    const fullPath = path.join(directory, file)
    const stats = await fs.promises.stat(fullPath)
    if (stats.isDirectory()) {
      await populateMap(fullPath, map)
    } else {
      map[file] = fullPath
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not an answer, that's a comment (or a hint)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I was able to follow your suggestions and it worked fine.